# Как использовать оператор or?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
userAnswer = input('Continue? (yes/no)')
userAnswer.lower()
while userAnswer != 'no' or userAnswer != 'yes':
```

Как правильно использовать оператор *or*?

Поодиночке всё работает, но когда делаю двойное условие, то просто не выходит из цикла.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас неправильное условие. `userAnswer` всегда не равен `'no'` или не равен '`yes'`, это следует из банальной логики. 
Вам подойдет следующее решение:

`while userAnswer not in ('yes', 'no'):`

Answer (score 1):

Решение пользователя @zzashpaupat отлично подходит к вашей задаче (а также очень легко читается и понимается), но если есть желание написать условие из двух частей, то необходимо понять следующие два пункта:

- цикл исполняется до тех пор, пока верно условие
- оператор `or` возвращает `true` в случае, если хотя бы один аргумент истинный

Использованное вами условие вернуло бы `false` только в случае, если строка **равна** одновременно и `'yes'`, и `'no'`, что невозможно, поэтому получился бесконечный цикл.

Если минимально изменять ваше решение, то можно использовать оператор `and`, так как он как раз и реализует требуемое вам поведение:

```
while userAnswer != 'no' and userAnswer != 'yes':
```

но оно читается чуть хуже, чем вариант, использующий отрицание:

```
while not (userAnswer == 'no' or userAnswer == 'yes'):
```

Здесь уже понятно, что если одно или другое исполняется, то мы выходим из цикла. Однако напомню, что ещё лучше читается решение из другого ответа.