# Проблемы с условием Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if result != ('2' or 'A'):
if not result == '2' or result == 'A'
if result != '2' or result != 'A'
```

я перепробовал всё это нечего не работает, а именно если result = 'A' он всё равно проходит через это условие. Помогите как сделать правильно

Comment: А какое должно быть условие? Словами. Первое условие у вас проверяет совсем не то, что вы думаете, в других случаях всегда одна из частей будет тру, поэтому и всё вместе тру. Почитайте, как работает or.

Comment: надо сделать так чтобы условие работало если result не равен '2' и не равен 'A'

Comment: для "И" нужно использовать and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответы верны, но не гибкие. Что, если потом надо будет проверить 3 условия? 4? 5? 6? Предлагаю более гибкий вариант:

```py
forbidden_results = ['2', 'A']
if result not in forbidden_results:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё проблема решена, помогло [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434226/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-or?rq=1).

Сделал так:

```
if not (result == '2' or result == 'A'):
```

Comment: О, ну или так :)

Answer (score 1):

Условие для result не равно 2 **и** result не равно "А" это

```
if result != '2' and result != 'A':
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут 3 условия. Возможно, вам стоит or на and сменить)

Comment: 3 условия это пример как я пытался сделать

Comment: if result != '2' and result != 'A'?

Comment: всё я уже разобрался посмотрите ответ МОЙ ниже

Comment: А вам именно с оператором or нужно? Через and вроде бы проще читается)